# Get Weekly records from Database

Tags: sql, postgresql

My database table  is something like this

```
CREATE TABLE issues
(
    id                  uuid,
    status              int,
    created_at          TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT SAMPLE**

```
Saturday :  2
SUNDAY : 2
MONDAY : 2
TUESDAY : 2
WEDNESDAY :2
THURSDAY : 2
FRIDAY :2
```

Comment: Please review the help section [ask].  The community will help you with your issues but it is **not a code writing service**. Not that code could be written without knowing the what the output means or the problem to  resolve. Describe what you are trying to accomplish, show what you have tried and what that produces.  Additionally you need to post sample input data - as text, **no images**.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT WEEK(created_at),WEEKDAY(created_at) as weekday,count(*) as weekly_count
FROM `issues`
WHERE WEEKDAY(created_at) > 1 AND WEEKDAY(created_at) < 6
GROUP BY WEEK(created_at)
```

Comment: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "`" Position: 86`  getting this error

Comment: I think this error comes because of your reaming code not for suggested query

Comment: sorry sir I am using postgres changed the tag